# instead of trigger and keeping unique values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a table (shown below) with a instead of trigger (code shown below)

MyTable:

```
 ID    directory    manager
 ---------------------------
 1     C:\Blah\     Bob
 2     C:\Blob\     Dave
```

`ID` is the primary key.

My trigger deals with insert, update & deletes. The deletes are not an issue. I would like that when inserting or updating a record in my table to ensure that the directory is unique. What is the best way to do this? `ID` has to be kept as a primary key.

My trigger code (stripped down),

```
create trigger trMyTable on MyTable
instead of insert, update, delete
as
begin
    declare @permission bit

    if exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        if exists(select * from deleted)
        begin                               -- its an update query
            update MyTable
            set directory = inserted.directory,
                manager = inserted.manager
            from inserted 
            inner join MyTable on inserted.ID = MyTable.ID;
        end             
        else
            insert into MyTable(directory, manager) 
                select 
                    directory, manager 
                from inserted;
    end
end
```

Comment: "ensure that the directory is unique" - then why not just apply a `unique` constraint on that column?

Comment: sorry I know very little about sql. So in my table setup I can apply a unique constraint on the directory column & then as my code is will be fine?

Comment: Yes, see [Create Unique Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190024(v=sql.110).aspx). There are other types of constraints also (foreign key, check, and you're already familiar with primary key constraint), you should try to use those in preference to writing triggers, if they're able to do the job.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT ux_MyTable_Directory UNIQUE (directory)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest method by far is what DavidG suggested as a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT ux_MyTable_Directory UNIQUE (directory)
```

To accomplish as a trigger, you can do the following to ensure your business requirement is met, but unless there is another reason for having the trigger (audits or whatever), then definitely consider the UNIQUE constraint. Even if you are using the trigger for security or audits, I would still use the UNIQUE constraint so you can change the trigger to be AFTER in lieu of INSTEAD OF so you can just do those functions instead of handling all your data operations as well.

```
create trigger trMyTable on MyTable
instead of insert, update, delete
as
begin
    declare @permission bit

    -- Verify no duplicate
    if exists(
        select *
        from inserted
        where exists (
            select *
            from MyTable
            where directory = inserted.directory
                and id <> inserted.id
        ))
    begin
        raiserror('Duplicate directory', 15, 99)
    end
    else
    begin

        -- Perform data changes
        if exists(select * from inserted)
        begin
            if exists(select * from deleted)
            begin                               -- its an update query
                update MyTable
                set directory = inserted.directory,
                    manager = inserted.manager
                from inserted 
                inner join MyTable on inserted.ID = MyTable.ID;
            end             
            else
                insert into MyTable(directory, manager) 
                    select 
                        directory, manager 
                    from inserted;
        end
        else
        begin
            delete MyTable where id in (select id from deleted)
        end
    end
end
```